# cb() never called! when installing @vue/cli

Tags: vue.js, npm, npm-install, vue-cli

Newbie here, I am trying to install vue cli for frontend development with npm, but it is throwing an error.

Here is the output of `sudo npm install -g @vue/cli`

```
[18:00 vue]$ sudo npm install -g @vue/cli 
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-01-18T13_06_37_662Z-debug.log
```

[Here is a complete log](https://gist.github.com/drdilyor/cc68a9b465403640bb1ea3bbea16ba5d)

I tried with and without sudo, the same error.

My machine runs Manjaro KDE 20.2, npm version 6.14.9, node v15.4.0. I have tried:

- retrying to see if it works this time
- `sudo npm cache verify` and `sudo npm cache clean --force`
- removing `/usr/lib/node_modules`
- reinstalling node and npm
- anything else i found on the internet

I'm stuck on this error for a few days, any help is appreciated.

It's interesting that it works without -g flag, installing to current folder, but I can't figure out how to use `vue` command then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i removed that Manjaro, and grabbed the latest version of ubuntu, this solved my problem, will never install Manjaro again.